# Dart mysql insert placeholders in map

Tags: mysql, dart, flutter

1) Is there some chance to insert huge placeholder via Map?

**Example:**

```
Map<String, dynamic> job = {
    'status': 'test',
    'id_sitemap': 2500,
    'id_job': 12,
    'contact_uuid': 'nejakeuuid',
    'id_source': 250,
     ...
     more 90 cols
  };

  await connection.query('INSERT INTO jobs', job);
```

2) How can I use mysql transaction? I'm using package `mysql1` for Dart.

Comment: "insert huge placeholder" what does that mean?

Comment: thats mean I have table with 95 columns and I dont want write VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,......) and use strict positions of placeholders. I want use Map where the key is column name and value is column value. For better reading code.

Comment: I see, but don't know.

Answer (score 1):

maybe its a little to late, but for others finding this post. You can do it in this way, not perfect, but little more flexible:

```
final sql = '''
  INSERT INTO jobs 
    (${job.keys.toList().join(',')}) 
  VALUES 
    (${List.filled(job.keys.length, '?').join(',')})   
''';
await connection.query(sql, job.values.toList());
```

Comment: Cool solution 